# Limit total messages displayed in the inbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to find the correct way to set a maximum number of messages to display in a users inbox without it disfiguring the pagination. I'm trying to make it so only the last 100 inbox messages are displayed from newest to oldest.

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

def index
@messages = current_user.received_messages.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page =>    15,  :order => 'created_at DESC', )
end
```

using the will_paginate gem

```
<%= will_paginate @messages %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def index
@messages = current_user.received_messages.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page =>    15).order('created_at DESC').limit(100)
end
```

or try with

```
def index
    @records = current_user.received_messages.order('created_at DESC').limit(100)
@messages = @records.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page =>    15)
    end
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Should the `.limit(100)` be put at the end or should it be put after `.received_messages`, like `@messages = current_user.received_messages.limit(100).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page =>    15).order('created_at DESC')`?

Comment: No that doesn't work. I tried something similar before but encountered the same problem. 

I have an account with 10 received messages... when I test the code by changing the maximum messages to display to 6 and per_page to 1.. it should only show me the last 6 messages and one per pagination.
With both code examples it still show every private message received.

Answer (score 0):

But it is a good practice to first implement the active_records conditions, than the pagination's.

```
def index
 @messages = current_user.received_messages.order(:created_at).reverse_order.limit(100).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
end
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Then in theory the below code should work:

def index
@messages = current_user.received_messages.limit(2).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
end

but it still displays all received messages... not just the last two.

Comment: I updated the answer, but still not able to understand, why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem before, My fix was:

```
require 'will_paginate/array' # To paginate an array instead of ActiveRecord
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

def index
@messages = current_user.received_messages.limit(100).all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15,  :order => 'created_at DESC') # I transform the resultset to an array using .all before the paginate
end
```